# How does Ember-CLI precompile templates?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Before moving to Ember-CLI, I had used Gulp where I created a task that would precompile the templates and add them to the `Ember.TEMPLATES` property. Ember would access the templates from there.

When working with Ember-CLI though, I noticed that `Ember.TEMPLATES` is an empty object and yet Ember is still able to resolve its templates. How does Ember-CLI do this?

Comment: ember-cli uses `broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler`, maybe it's a good idea to take a look here https://github.com/toranb/broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler, and that uses this https://github.com/toranb/ember-template-compiler