# How does ember-qunit render components in integration testing?

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit, ember-testing

Here is a basic component / integration test for ember-qunit.

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('my-component', 'TODO: put something here', {
  integration: true
});

test('it renders', function(assert) {
  this.render(hbs`{{my-component}}`);

  console.log('This is the rendered element', this.$()[0]);
  assert.ok(false);
});
```

I have an ember-addon with a directory structure like this:

```
addon/
.. components/
.... my-component/
...... component.js
...... style.less
...... template.hbs   
app/  
.. components/
.... my-component.js
...... component.js
tests/  
.. integration/  
.... components/  
...... my-component-test.js
```

How does ember determine where `{{my-component}}` is?

This is kind of in the same vein as this:
[How does Ember-CLI precompile templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034489/how-does-ember-cli-precompile-templates)

## Edit 1

As per the comments, I've linked the regular `app` component to the `addon` component by just importing / exporting it.

```
app/components/my-component/component.js
export { default } from 'my-application/components/my-component'
```

However, the console log only shows this:

```
This is the rendered element <div id="ember234 class="ember-view">
                               <!---->
                             </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention.

Ember try to find a file named `my-component` under your `app/components` directory or `app/components/templates` directory or `app/helpers` directory.

If you define `my-component` under your `addon/components` directory, you need to re-define it under your `app/components` directory or `tests/dummy/app/components` directory such as:

```
export { default } from 'my-addon/components/my-component';
```

Comment: Two questions here. First, how do the other parts of a component figure in, like template and styles (updated file structure to include them) alongside the `component.js` in addons. Second, if the component is defined in `tests` and `app`, which does it default to? (Question updated to Edit 1)

Comment: Do you import `layout` from your `component.js`? It seems you are not importing a template. Have a look at [this addon](https://github.com/tubitak-bilgem-yte/ember-contextual-table). It has integration tests.

Comment: I tried adding  
`import template from './template'; &   layout: template to addon/components/my-component/component.js before to no avail unfortunately

Comment: I like the addon link you have there. The primary differences I see are that the addon's component is broken into components/ and templates/ instead of my all-in-one approach. They also use block components {{#component}}, but I don' think that's my issue

Comment: templates has to be under `app/templates` directory.