# How to add integration tests for components defined in an ember-addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit, ember-testing, ember-addon, ember-pods

Here is the structure of my ember-addon.

```
addon/
.. components/
.... my-component/
...... component.js
...... style.less
...... template.hbs   
.. engine.js
.. routes.js
app/  
.. components/
.... my-component/
...... component.js
.. etc ..
tests/  
.. dummy/
.... app/
...... components/
...... controllers/
...... etc ....
.. integration/  
.... components/  
...... my-component-test.js  
.. index.html
.. test-helper.js
```

The test file `tests/integration/components/my-component-test.js`:

```
//tests/integration/component/my-component-test.js
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('my-component', 'my component module description', {
  integration: true
});

test('it renders', function(assert) {
  this.render(hbs`{{my-component}}`);

  console.log('This rendered', this.$()[0]);
  assert.ok(false);
});
```

I link to my addon from `app/` as well:

```
//app/components/my-component/component.js
export { default } from 'my-application/components/my-component/component'
```

Let's say that my component template looks something like this:

```
<!-- addon/components/my-component/template.hbs -->
<div class="foo"></div>
```

And let's say that my component's js file looks something like this:

```
//addon/components/my-component/component.js
import Ember from 'ember'
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    someProperty: 'someValue'
});
```

---

I would assume that the output of the console log would be:

```
<div id="ember234" class="ember-view>
    <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
```

But unfortunately the console in Qunit comes up with:

```
<div id="ember234" class="ember-view">
    <!---->
</div>
```

Is Ember just struggling to find my `.hbs` template? Other projects seem to do all their component tests with the standard grouping (ie having named component js files and template files rather than `component.js` and `template.js`).

https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday

This relates to another question I asked, but I thought it more appropriate to continue probing this testing issue here in a separate question.

[How does ember-qunit render components in integration testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236852/how-does-ember-qunit-render-components-in-integration-testing)

I also question if there is a specific way necessary to test this pod layout.

Comment: Even with the changes (and accepted answer), it appears that the inside of the rendered component is abstracted away when logged to the console. Maybe it's a jQuery thing. But does anybody know why it refuses to show more than `<!---->` when I can definitely search for `this.$('div')`? Perhaps that's another question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `component.js` has to import template as `layout`. You should do this:

```
//addon/components/my-component/component.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from '../../templates/components/my-component/template'

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    layout,
    someProperty: 'someValue'
});
```

I can suggest you to have a look at other addons' codes. Such as [ember-contextual-table](https://github.com/tubitak-bilgem-yte/ember-contextual-table/blob/master/addon/components/data-paginator.js#L5), [ember-bootstrap](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/addon/components/bs-tab.js#L109).

Comment: This ended up working for me, with a few caveats. I changed layout to import from `./templates` and changed my `app/components/my-component/component.js` to `export { default } from 'my-application/components/my-component/component'`. Now I can do `this.$('div')` and find results. Awesome! (updated the mentioned `component.js` file above too!

Comment: Above comment should be `./template`. (sorry, 5 minute edit window)